# right join not giving values null

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have two tables as:

```
select * from CallTypeDescription
select * from CallTypeDetails
```

[image]

I want to show all the records of idcalltype against its idjob.

Eg.

If idJob in `CallTypeDescription` is 96 and idCallType is 4 it should show records:

[image]

if idJob is 94 (i.e. does not exists in callType description) and idCallType is 4  then result should be:

```
Title        Value   idJob

test qu1      Null    Null

test qu2      Null    Null
```

For this i tried:

```
select a.Title,b.Value,b.idJob from  CallTypeDescription b
right join CallTypeDetails a
on a.idCallType=b.idCallType
and a.idDetails=b.idCallTypeDetail
where a.idCallType=4 and b.idJob=96
```

But gives me result:

[image]

It should also add another row with test qu2 null null.

Plese help me.

**Edit:**

```
select a.Title,b.Value,b.idJob from  CallTypeDescription b
    right join CallTypeDetails a
    on a.idCallType=b.idCallType
    and a.idDetails=b.idCallTypeDetail
    and a.idCallType=4 
    where  b.idJob=96
```

Comment: You need to move the condition `a.idCallType=4` from the where clause to the `join` clause. As it is, this turns your outer join into an inner join.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name tried as u said, but not working, see my edit

Comment: `and a.idDetails=b.idCallTypeDetail`
is causing the output that you have observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are after this effect (SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f98e/10):

```
select
  a.Title,b.Value,b.idJob
from
  (
    select
      IdDesc, 
      IdCallType,
      IdJob,
      IdCallTypeDetail,
      Value
    from
      CallTypeDescription
    where
      IdJob = 96 --or 94
  ) b
right outer join
  CallTypeDetails a
on
  a.idCallType=b.idCallType
and
  a.idDetails=b.idCallTypeDetail
where
  a.idCallType=4
```

Is there a reason you have chosen to use a right join instead of a left one?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line that constrains the query to only return rows where the idDetails and isCallTypeDetail are equal:

`select a.Title,b.Value,b.idJob 
from  CallTypeDescription b inner join CallTypeDetails a 
      on a.idCallType=b.idCallType
where a.idCallType=4 and b.idJob=96`

Comment: This doesn't give the expected result OP is after (http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp6aM.jpg)